# Function for dungeon crawler not working

Tags: python

I'm building a basic dungeon crawler game and I cant seem to get one of my functions to work properly. I've tried playing around with the indentation to see if it was caused by that but no luck so far, this is the function in it's current state:

```
def prisoner_encounter():
    global player_health
    global room_count
    scroll_text("\nYou kick open a rusted metal door and a faint raspy voice calls out to you from inside the darkness.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nHey...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nHey you...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nPlease help me...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nYou look at the rotting old man, he's chained to wall by all four limbs.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")

    security = True
    while security == True:

        choice = input("\nDo you try to help him? [ y | n ] ")
        print("\n ")
        if choice == "y" or choice == "n":
             security = False

        if choice == "y":
            yes_choice = random.randint(1,2)

        if yes_choice == "1":
            scroll_text("\nYou spend what seems like an eternity fiddling with the lock. Finally you hear a click and the chains fall to the ground.")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("\n ")
            scroll_text("\nThe old man thanks you for your help and tends to some of your wounds, +2 health.")
            player_health = player_health + 2
            time.sleep(1)

        if yes_choice == "2":
            scroll_text("\nYou spot a rock in the corner of the cell and use it to smash the lock off the man's chains.")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("\n ")
            scroll_text("\nUnexpectedly the man sucker punches you in the side of the head and disappears down the corridor, -2 health.")
            player_health = player_health - 2
            time.sleep(1)

        if choice == "n":
            scroll_text("\nYou apologise to the man and explain that must keep moving in order to escape. You try not to think about him.")
            time.sleep(1)
```

What it's supposed to do is give you a yes or no option to help a man, if you pick yes, there's a good outcome and a bad outcome with a 50/50 chance each, if you pick no you just carry on.

Comment: So, are you getting an error message?

Comment: nope not currently, but when I type in the yes or no answer it just does nothing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help us help you and in the long run could provide others with useful information if they come across this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues. First, your branching logic for the `choice == "y"` condition should be indented one level. Second, `randint` will return an integer, so your comparisons should remove the quotation marks around the integers `1` and `2`:

```
def prisoner_encounter():
    global player_health
    global room_count
    scroll_text("\nYou kick open a rusted metal door and a faint raspy voice calls out to you from inside the darkness.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nHey...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nHey you...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nPlease help me...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")
    scroll_text("\nYou look at the rotting old man, he's chained to wall by all four limbs.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n ")

    security = True
    while security == True:

        choice = input("\nDo you try to help him? [ y | n ] ")
        print("\n ")
        if choice == "y" or choice == "n":
             security = False

        if choice == "y":
            yes_choice = random.randint(1,2)

            if yes_choice == 1:
                scroll_text("\nYou spend what seems like an eternity fiddling with the lock. Finally you hear a click and the chains fall to the ground.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("\n ")
                scroll_text("\nThe old man thanks you for your help and tends to some of your wounds, +2 health.")
                player_health = player_health + 2
                time.sleep(1)

            elif yes_choice == 2:
                scroll_text("\nYou spot a rock in the corner of the cell and use it to smash the lock off the man's chains.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("\n ")
                scroll_text("\nUnexpectedly the man sucker punches you in the side of the head and disappears down the corridor, -2 health.")
                player_health = player_health - 2
                time.sleep(1)

        elif if choice == "n":
            scroll_text("\nYou apologise to the man and explain that must keep moving in order to escape. You try not to think about him.")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If I've answered your question, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from gray to green.